# Calculating html column values based on another column and an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I insert a value into a html table column (using Javascript or jQuery), based on the values from another column and an input field.

For example (see code below), if I enter the number `115` in the input field the column `advance` should display the value `1` for each athlete where their number in column `second` is lower than the number in the input field, if the number is higher the value of athlete in the advance column should become `0`.

The number of columns will vary but the values in the column seconds will always have a class name *"seconds"* and the values in the column advance will always have the class name *"advance"*.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Athlete</th>
    <th>Seconds</th>
    <th>Advance</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A.E.</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td class="advance">.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>G.F.</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td class="advance">.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>T.L</td>
    <td>110</td>
    <td class="advance">.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="number">
<button id="btn">
        Confirm
        </button>
```

Thanks for taking your time

Comment: Can you should us your jQuery code of what you have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, to solve this I added an id to your number input; see here:

```
<input id='number' type="number">
```

and when creating each athlete's row, add a class 'athlete-data' to the "< tr >" for each one. Like this:

```
<tr class='athlete-data'>
 <td>G.F.</td>
 <td>90</td>
 <td class="advance">.</td>
</tr>
```

Finally, here is the Javascript

```
//Grab all the athlete rows by the class we added to the <tr>'s'
let athleteRows = document.getElementsByClassName('athlete-data');

//Listen for button click
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', ()=> {
let number = document.getElementById('number').value;
filterAthletes(number);
});


function filterAthletes(limit){
    //Iterate over the athlete rows
    for(let row of athleteRows){

    //Get their time
    let athleteTime = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[1].textContent;

    //Compare them, and set the text content.
    if (parseFloat(athleteTime) >= parseFloat(limit)){
      row.getElementsByClassName('advance')[0].textContent = '1';
    }
   else {
      row.getElementsByClassName('advance')[0].textContent = '0';
    }
   }
 }
```